# Django Admin Custom Inline Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

My question is about django admin inline model,

in Django admin site the inline model looks like this:

[image]

the many to many objects appear in a dropdown.
is there anyway (or a library) to show all the objects in a table and each row with a checkbox so the user could select each object they want?

thank you for helping

sorry about the image quality

Comment: Don't get clearly - do you want objects in a dropdown with checkboxes?

Comment: @Chiefir no i don't want the dropdown, i want each object in one row with a checkbox. like models change list in admin site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, I change tabular.html template showed all records and added extra js to only send selected rows